# PHP echo array of array within ""

Tags: php, string, echo

```
for($i=0;$i<count($some_array);$i++){
   echo "<h3 name=$some_array[2][$i]>$some_array[1][$i]</h3>";      
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Is it possible to echo a value of an array of an array within "" without using this annoying combining-strings-method?

```
echo "<h3 name=" . $some_array[2][$i] . ">" . $some_array[1][$i]. "</h3>";
```

Comment: Read the manual. Use "curly" syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo "<h3 name={$some_array[2][$i]}>{$some_array[1][$i]}</h3>";
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `count($some_array[1])`, because now you only count `$some_array[x]` and not how many keys  `$some_array[x][y]` where `y` is.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 echo '<h3 name="'.$some_array[2][$i].'">'.$some_array[1][$i].'</h3>';
```

Also consider the execution cost & potential error of using count within the loop.  Instead consider

```
$cnt = count($some_array);
for($=0;$i<$count;$i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the manual on [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Essentially, for expressions you need to use the "{}" or "Complex (curly) syntax" with double quotes.

```
$some_array[0]
```

Would work without the complex curly syntax, but you accessing another level deep of an array, hence it not working.